# Is there a term for question which is actually not a question but a statement or opinion?

Tags: terminology, questions

For example, questions of type "Why do you hate XXXXXX" when a person doesn't actually hate that XXXXXX.

Comment: Your example has some overlap with a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question).

Comment: Looks like a [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question).

Comment: Or it could simply be a misconception.

Comment: It's possibly hyperbole (exaggeration, for example by a child), but if calculated, is actually a lie ('Why do you hate X?' entails 'You hate X.').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is called a **[strawman fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman)** which is defined as misrepresenting someone's argument to make it easier to attack.  An example from *[Your Logical Fallacy Is](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/)* (a great website for fallacies in general) is this:

> After Will said that we should put more money into health and education, Warren responded by saying that he was surprised that Will hates our country so much that he wants to leave it defenceless by cutting military spending.

Hope that helps.